# Accessing Session Object in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, session

I am setting a Session using Spring HttpSession.
Here session is set as a object containing four/five fields.
I can access this session at my jsp but when i want to access the individual records within the Sessionobject. it gives null.
Help please
// This is session data model

```
public class UserServiceModel implements Serializable 
{

    public String MobileNo;
    public String CityName;
    public String UserName;
    public String UserPwd;
    public String UserRole;
    public String Device;
    public UUID SessionID;

// getters,setters
}
```

// code for setting session

```
StaffModel  record1 =   (StaffModel) data.get("records");            

        UserServiceModel sessionData = new UserServiceModel();
        sessionData.setMobileNo(record1.getMobileNo());
        sessionData.setCityName(record1.getCity());
        sessionData.setUserName(record1.getFirstName());
        sessionData.setUserRole(record1.getRole());
        sessionData.SessionID   =   UUID.randomUUID();

        System.out.println("SessionID=" + sessionData.MobileNo);

        sessionObj.setAttribute("SessionData" , sessionData);                   // setting session Data
```

// this is jsp code

```
<%  String ses  = (String)session.getAttribute("SessionData.MobileNo"); 
            out.print("Hello User:"+ses);
        %>
```

Output gives: null

Answer (score 0):

You have update the JSP code like below. As session.getAttribute() method return object as value.

```
<%  
UserServiceModel  obj= (UserServiceModel)session.getAttribute("SessionData");
String ses  = obj.getMobileNo();
out.print("Hello User:"+ses);
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this

Here is the code:

```
sUserName   =   <% UserServiceModel obj =   (UserServiceModel)session.getAttribute("SessionData");
                            out.print(obj.getUserName());
```

// at top of the jsp page i have to import the model UserServiceModel

```
<%@ page import="org.kmsg.listobject.UserServiceModel"%>
```

and now userName which exist within the object SessionData is accessible in variable "sUserName"

Thanks...